# DLL registration return code 0x80029c4a

Tags: c++, windows, com

I'm fairly new to COM programming and I have a DLL that compiles, but wont register when I attempt to run it. I followed this tutorial here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2wad1c0e(v=vs.80) and modified it to produce the code bellow. I'm not quite sure what I did wrong here.

```
#pragma once
#define STRICT
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#endif
#define _ATL_ATTRIBUTES
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
#define _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
#include <atltypes.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#include <atlhost.h>
using namespace ATL;

[module(type=dll, 
        name = "SMTPSink",
        version="1.0",
        uuid="0933FDCB-7CA1-41C7-BBA0-D1EF8C76F7A7",
        helpstring = "SMTPSink SMTPSink type library 1.0") ];
[ emitidl ];

//SMTP server interface functions.
//#import "oaidl.idl";
//#import "ocidl.idl";


#import "msado15.dll"  raw_interfaces_only no_namespace 
#import "cdosys.dll"  raw_interfaces_only rename_namespace("TWGSMTP") raw_native_types no_implementation
#import "seo.dll"  raw_interfaces_only no_namespace 

#include "Config_Loader.h"
using namespace TWGSMTP;
//struct IMessage;

[
   object,
   uuid("6F6CC19F-FC41-4FFD-95BD-717FFE9549E5"),
   dual,
   helpstring("Sink Interface"),
   pointer_default(unique)
]
__interface ISink : ISMTPOnArrival
{
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnArrival (/*[in]*/ IMessage * Msg,
        /*[in,out]*/ enum CdoEventStatus * EventStatus );
};

[
   coclass,
   threading(apartment),
   vi_progid("TWG.Sink"),
   progid("TWG.Sink.1"),
   version(1.0),
   uuid("17349758-26FD-49C0-894C-4C59D30F95CD"),
   helpstring("Sink Class")
]
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Sink: 
    public ISink
{
public:
   Sink()
   {
   }
   HRESULT __stdcall OnArrival (struct IMessage * Msg, enum CdoEventStatus * EventStatus );
   void TestMethod();

   HRESULT FinalConstruct()
   {
      return S_OK;
   }

   void FinalRelease() 
   {
   }
};
```

Comment: 0x80029c4a is `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY`.  Are you trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process or vice-versa, maybe?

Comment: My target machine is a windows 2003 server R2 which is 32-bit only. My RC was just missing a TYPELIB line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a simple case of my RC file not having the

```
1                       TYPELIB           "SMTPSink.tlb"
```

line. Don't know why it wasn't there in the first place.